# getting InvalidCastException when querying databse, if query is copied into new query on the db it works sucessfully

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqlconnection

on a page in my application when the submit button is hit, the information from the form above is to be stored into the database. I am getting this error when I run the program, but if I am to use breakpoints and copy the SQLtext string then paste this code into a new query on the DB manager it works. The error always says the following, but "Speed" is different depending on the value from ddlDrugs  (for example, if we selected Alcohol, the error would say Conversion from string "Alcohol" to type 'Integer' is not valid) :

```
Conversion from string "Speed" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Does anyone see why this is happening? ddlDrugs is a dropdown in which is populated using a post back triggered when ddlDrugType is changed. Listed below first is the sub when the submit button is hit, and below that the function that binds the dropdown.

```
    Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim objGetConnInfo As New ConnInfo
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = objGetConnInfo.GetConnString
    Dim objConn As SqlConnection
    objConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
    myCmd = New SqlCommand
    myCmd.Connection = objConn
    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim ds As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    objConn.Open()
    Dim fName As String = txtfName.Text
    Dim lName As String = txtlName.Text
    Dim DOB As String = ddlDOBmonth.SelectedValue & "/" & ddlDOBday.SelectedValue & "/" & ddlDOByear.SelectedValue
    Dim sexChoice As Integer = rdoSex.SelectedIndex
    Dim sex As String
    If sexChoice = 0 Then
        sex = "m"
    ElseIf sexChoice = 1 Then
        sex = "f"
    End If
    Dim SSN As String = txtSSN.Text
    Dim address As String = txtAddress.Text
    Dim city As String = txtCity.Text
    Dim state As String = ddlState.SelectedValue
    Dim zip As String = txtZip.Text
    Dim phone As String = txtPhone1.Text
    Dim cellPhone As String = txtPhone2.Text
    Dim altPhone As String = txtPhone3.Text
    Dim EC As String = txtECname.Text
    Dim relationshipIndex As Integer = ddlECrelationship.SelectedValue
    myCmd.CommandText = "Select Name from Relationships where ID = " & relationshipIndex
    Dim relationship As String = myCmd.ExecuteScalar

    Dim ECphone As String = txtECphone.Text
    Dim findRRindex As Integer = ddlHowRR.SelectedValue
    myCmd.CommandText = "Select Name from foundRR where ID =" & findRRindex
    Dim findRR As String = myCmd.ExecuteScalar
    Dim rush As String
    If chkRush.Checked = True Then
        rush = "1"
    Else
        rush = "0"
    End If

    Dim reason As String = txtReason.Text
    Dim drugType As String = ddlDrugType.SelectedValue
    Dim drugIndex As Integer = ddlDrug.SelectedValue
    myCmd.CommandText = "Select Drug from " & drugType & " where Id = " & drugIndex
    Dim drugObj As Object = myCmd.ExecuteScalar
    Dim drug As String = ddlDrug.SelectedItem.Text

    Dim previous As String = txtPrevTreatment.Text
    Dim dateCompleted As String = ddlDOCmonth.SelectedValue & "/" & ddlDOCdate.SelectedValue & "/" & ddlDOCyear.SelectedValue
    Dim treatmentRep As String = txtTreatmentRep.Text
    Dim test As String = ddlDrug.SelectedValue



    '                        insert into Clients values ('mike','abramowitz','9/12/1986', 'm', 187664309, '2132 mather way',                               'elkins park', 'pa', 19027, '2222222222','3333', '4', 'dad', 'mom',                                                            '55', 'magic', 0, 'need it', 'drug type',                                              'pot', 'none', '9/12/1988', 'tim')
    Dim SQLtext As String = "exec insertClient '" & fName & "','" & lName & "','" & DOB & "', '" & sex & "'," & SSN & ", '" & address & "', '" & city & "', '" & state & "', " & zip & ", '" & phone & "','" & cellPhone & "', '" & altPhone & "', '" & EC & "', '" & relationship & "', '" & ECphone & "', '" & findRR & "'," & rush & ", '" & reason & "', ' " & drugType & "','" & drug & "', '" & previous & "', ' " & dateCompleted & "', '" & treatmentRep & "')"



    Dim clientID As Integer = myCmd.ExecuteScalar
    objConn.Close()
    myCmd.Dispose()


End Sub
```

Binding the dropdown on postback

```
    Protected Sub ddlDrugType_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim objGetConnInfo As New ConnInfo
    Dim strConn As String
    strConn = objGetConnInfo.GetConnString
    Dim objConn As SqlConnection
    objConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
    myCmd = New SqlCommand
    myCmd.Connection = objConn
    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    Dim ds As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
    myCmd.CommandText = "Select Id, Drug from " & ddlDrugType.SelectedValue
    objConn.Open()
    ds = myCmd.ExecuteReader
    ddlDrug.DataSource = ds
    ddlDrug.DataTextField = "Drug"
    ddlDrug.DataValueField = "Id"
    ddlDrug.DataBind()
    ds.Close()

    objConn.Close()

    myCmd.Dispose()


End Sub
```

and here is the detailed error

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
```

HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Conversion from string "Speed" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(Object Value)
       at RR.NewCustomer.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\RR\RR\NewCustomer.aspx.vb:line 276
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.FormatException
       HResult=-2146233033
       Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
       Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
            at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
       InnerException:

edit: here is the code for the actual dropdowns

```
<asp:dropdownlist style="Z-INDEX: 0" id="ddlDrugType" 
                                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDrugType_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" 
                                Height="16px" ViewStateMode="Enabled" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:dropdownlist>

<asp:dropdownlist style="Z-INDEX: 0" id="ddlDrug" runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the html code for ddlDrug. I am suspecting you have something like

```
<option selected="selected" value="Speed">Speed</option>
<option value="Alchol">Alchol</option>
```

Instead you should have some sort of ID for the value.

or you need to change

```
Dim drugIndex As Integer = ddlDrug.SelectedValue
```

to

```
Dim drugIndex As String = ddlDrug.SelectedValue
```

Comment: edited first post to show the drop downs, and the bottom part of the above answer is incorrect. drugIndex is the value of the drop down, i then use an sql statement to get the string, so it doesn't matter if its int or string - still getting the same error in the end.

Comment: You showed the ddlDrug before the options were added... Your ID is obviously "Speed" and then you are trying to pass a string into an integer which is why the error is occurring. Try changing drugIndex to a string as I suggested. At least that way you will continue on.

Comment: I have changed drugIndex to a string and it makes no difference.

Comment: Can you put some try catch around your code and then you will be able to find out where the error is happening